# Scipy Sparse Random using Numpy default_rng

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using the `scipy.sparse.random` function to generate random sparse matrices with `m,n > 1000`, a given density and my upstream programs work:

```
import numpy
from scipy import sparse
from numpy.random import default_rng

numpy.random.seed(41)
S = sparse.random(m, n, density=0.25, format='csr')
```

However, when using the `numpy.random.default_rng` function, the upstream programs don't work:

```
rng = default_rng(seed=41)
S = sparse.random(m, n, density=0.25, format='csr', random_state=rng)
```

Any ideas why this should be?

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.random.html

Comment: *"[...] the upstream programs don't work"*  What does "doesn't work" mean in this case?  Do you get an error?  If so, include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  Or do you get unexpected results?  If so, show what you got and what you expected.  It would also be helpful to include the versions of NumPy and SciPy that you are using.

Comment: No error message. Unexpected results obtained using default_rng(). Cannot show comparative results because they would be meaningless. Sorry. Using Numpy 1.19.5, Scipy 1.6.2. Will run default_rng() again and leave comment.

Comment: Even with the same seed, don't expect the `rng` to produce the same numbers as the default.

Comment: Get the first N random bits from each stream with the same seed to see that they don't match. You pretty much need to pick a RNG and stick with it if you want reproducibility.

Comment: @hpaulj Wasn't expecting the rng and the default with the same seed to produce the same numbers. But, was expecting similar results in the upstream work. It appears as if the numbers are coming from different distributions. Questions: How do you test if the rng and default are "similar" wrt scipy.sparse.random?

Comment: I was guessing that because you set the seed, you expected the same numbers.  Otherwise there's little reason specify the seed, for either generator.  I don't see why using the `rng` would produce anything statistically different.  Your "different results in upsteam work" is too vague to help us help you.

Comment: A side note, don't use anymore global seeds with `np.random.seed`. We are slowly going to remove this. Have a look at NEP19 for more info.https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html